# Vertical spacing on the WEB?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

**The Question**

I was always wondering if there is some kind of a standard, specification or perhaps a CSS framework with definitions or guidelines on how to add uniform vertical spacing between elements?

When I think about coding for the web I always imagine it as a nice grid, where there is an uniform horizontal gutter between columns or horizontally stacked elements, and again an uniform vertical gutter between elements.

But what would be the best way to achieve this, preferably in conjunction with using Twitter Bootstrap for a WordPress theme?

---

**Margin Collapsing**

My first thought is always to set `margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px` on elements. Then, when they flow one under another they would always have exactly `50px` gutter between them thanks to [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

I still think this is a really nice approach as you wouldn't have to worry if the element is the first one, the last one or somewhere in between.

Furthermore, even if you nest elements, the margins would still collapse!

See the following example with nested elements which use paddings instead of margins (which do not collapse): http://jsfiddle.net/8wwrwy90

You can clearly see that the vertical gutters are anything but uniform.

Now see the same example with margins, which do collapse: http://jsfiddle.net/9rLaLso7/1

No matter how deep you nest, the margins collapse up to the root element and the gutter stays uniform. It's simply beautiful.

---

**The Problem**

As you can probably imagine there is an issue with this approach, which is exactly where I'm stuck. Margins only collapse under certain conditions and a lot of things can break it, from having clearance, through having set vertical paddings, to floating.

So, my general issue is with the otherwise awesome Twitter Bootstrap grid system. Simply said, columns use `float: left`, so from the moment you enter a column there is no more margin collapsing.

That simply breaks everything.

So, I've started looking for hacks around this issue, but haven't really found a good solution just yet.

Just so you would visualize the issue, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/19Leuhsq/1

I *good* solution would be one that would either allow for collapsing (which I believe can't happen with how the current grid system is made) or "compensate" for it. It would also be nice if one would be able to nest rows into rows into rows... and still get the same result, visually.

For me, it is important to be able to use any element anywhere as the markup will be automatically generated and built by the user from the admin panel in WordPress. So, I could not really rely on hard-coding distances or too complex rules like *if this is in that* or *if that follows that, but has no children or is the last element* etc.

---

**Wrap Up**

I'd really appreciate it if anyone would be able to point me into the right direction. Perhaps my approach is wrong, perhaps there is or there is no "standard" solution...

I am open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a different rendering mode called [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which solves all of these issues ([top-tier browsers only](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)).

Comment: That is worth investigating, but I'm not sure exactly how could I use this since, as far as I know, FlexBox does not support margin collapsing...

Answer (score 2):

I tend to avoid using top margins for this reason. You could just use the margin on the bottom and wrap the divs in a container with top padding to compensate for the first item.

```
div:not([class]) {
    margin: 0 0 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/19Leuhsq/2/

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but could you also modify it to account for rows nested in elements which are in a column: http://jsfiddle.net/19Leuhsq/6/ I think that might do the trick.

Comment: @TonyBogdanov I think in this case you should give the container of elements that have content a different class, so they won't get margin.

Comment: @johnnyd23 I think a modified version of your solution might just do the trick. Here's what should be added: *If a non-margin-collapse-propagating element has a non-margin-collapse-propagating child following any element, that child must compensate for the margin of it's previous sibling*. Or put in CSS, that would be `[class*="col-"] > * + .row { margin-top: -20px; }`, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/cq0qsx3q/2

Comment: I feel like you were overcomplicating your example by including an extra div around one of the rows - I commented that div out and it still works without the need for a negative top margin: http://jsfiddle.net/19Leuhsq/10/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if a child uses `float` then the margin collapsing doesn't apply on that element.

You could target the first and last childs of floated elements and reset their margin:

```
div.col-xs-6 div:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

div.col-xs-6 div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/19Leuhsq/4/

Or you could not use margin collapsing at all and use paddings of `25px` everywhere instead of margins of `50px`, and then have a container that adds `25px` to the top and bottom:

```
.container {
    padding: 25px 0;
}

div:not([class]) {
    padding: 25px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/19Leuhsq/7/

Comment: That would only work if you only have a single row of elements in each `<div class="row">`. When columns start wrapping to the next row (which is totally fine in bootstrap v3), things break: http://jsfiddle.net/19Leuhsq/5/

Comment: As I understand it, neither float nor flexbox support margin collapsing, so is it even worth it, or am I missing something?

Comment: @TonyBogdanov You might be right about margin collapsing in flexbox so I removed that from my answer. I added an alternative solution, using no margin collapsing.

Comment: The collapsing does the actual magic, paddings do not really help with anything. Try adding N-number of nested elements and watch it fail: http://jsfiddle.net/19Leuhsq/9